# Pushing ViewController from app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am using a storyboard in Xcode 5, which appears as so:

[image: storyboard screenshot]

My requirement is to push a ViewController (VIEW1 or VIEW2) into view from the app delegate. Essentially it should not matter what view is presently on the screen -- I would just like to make a ViewController appear when the app delegate picks up an external event.

In order to try and achieve this, I have property references to both the TabBarCtrl-Products and NavCtrl-ProductA in my app delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    _tabBarProducts = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sidTabBarProducts"];

    NSArray *tabvcs = _tabBarProducts.viewControllers;
    for (id controller in tabvcs){
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[VCNavControl_ProductA class]]) {
            _navControllerProductA = controller;
            break;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The app delegate method to push VIEW2 is:

```
-(void)showVCVIEW2
{
    VC_V2 *targetvc = nil;
    targetvc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sidView2"];
    [[AppDelegate sharedInstance].navControllerProductA pushViewController:targetvc animated:NO];
}
```

This works OK when VIEW1 is showing at the time showVCVIEW2 is called, however it does not work when ViewCtrl-ProductB is showing.  I can see that the new instance of targetvc has been added to the AppDelegate _navControllerProductA's stack, however it does not display.

*(Regarding the setting of the the app delegate's rootViewController, I set this to _tabBarProducts after the VC-Splash and VC-Setup ViewCtrls have finished).*

I would appreciate very much if anyone can give me an idea on how to achieve this.  I suspect my problems stem from having a NavCtrl in a TabBarCtrl, but I do not know a way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the navigation controller you are pushing on is not in the view hierarchy.

You instead could try setting the `tabBarController`'s selected index like this:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: The selected index required was 0, but it worked liked a charm. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem! Set it to 1 or 0 to toggle between your views.